# Why the [division] between this tag and [divide]?

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both tags seem to refer to the division of numbers by a denominator. [divide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/divide) has about 600 questions and [division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/division) has about 200. [divide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/divide) also has a vague tag description:

> Separate or be separated into parts

I think this synonym would be useful:

[divide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/divide) -> [division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/division)

If not, why not? How can [divide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/divide) be used separately from [division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/division)?

Comment: Just an observation. I see that some questions refer to the action of creating a partition when using `divide`, as in divide into sections (arrays, columns, strings). I'm not seeing this with `division`.

Comment: I don't see both tags referring to division of numbers. The description for `[divide]` states "Separate or be separated into parts".